# Threadcrossing ObservableCollection and DataGrid -> Race Condition

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

I have the following problem. I have a USB Device sending an XML stream at the SerialPort. This stream I serialize to a `List<myObject>`. This works fine. Then I have an `MTObservableCollection<myObject>` which inherites from `ObservableCollection<T>` and overrides `OnCollectionChanged` and `CollectionChanged`. I must confess that I have found this code in the web and for me it is hard to understand because I'm not an expert.

```
public class MTObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public override event System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var eh = CollectionChanged;
            if (eh != null)
            {
                System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher dispatcher = (from System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler nh in eh.GetInvocationList()
                                                                  let dpo = nh.Target as System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject
                                                                  where dpo != null
                                                                  select dpo.Dispatcher).FirstOrDefault();

                if (dispatcher != null && dispatcher.CheckAccess() == false)
                {
                    dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.DataBind, (Action)(() => OnCollectionChanged(e)));
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler nh in eh.GetInvocationList())
                        nh.Invoke(this, e);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc) { MessageBox.Show(exc.Message); }
    }
}
```

This Collection is bound to a DataGrid. The problem happens only sometimes, that's why I assume a race condition. When I clear the Collection and Add the `List<myObject>` Elements to it, I get an Exception not caught in the code shown below. At the moment I can not reproduce it because the device is at work. But maybe someone might see the promblem in the code.

```
public MTObservableCollection<DataFile> dataFiles = new MTObservableCollection<DataFile>();

try
{
    this.dataFiles.Clear();
    foreach (DataFile file in (List<DataFile>)data.Data)
    dataFiles.Add(file);
}
catch (Exception exc) { MessageBox.Show(exc.InnerException.Message); }
```

Comment: Just don't use any code that you don't understand... use an `ObservableCollection<T>` instead.

Comment: That's not possible because the access comes from the SerialPort and is thread crossing. As the Collection is bound to a DataGrid using an normal ObservableCollection would cause an Exception.

Comment: You could use an ordinary `ObservableCollection` if you had a layer in between the `Stream` and the UI that simply added items into the collection as and when they become available.

Comment: But somehow I have to change the thread. Could you state this a bit more precisely, please?

Comment: All your code is doing is calling the [`Dispatcher.Invoke` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx) using the UI thread `Dispatcher` to queue work items onto the UI thread. (Well, it's checking whether it's already on the UI thread first). Seriously though... if you're going to work with threads in any shape or form, then you really should learn how to. See the [Threading Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find a solution. I used a timer instead of SerialPot just to have second thread and added several Items to the Collection in the timer callback. I followed your hint and took an ordinary ObservableCollection. Finally it works, but please could you have a look at the code and give a remark if there is something to improve. I would really appreciate this.

```
private void timerCallback(Object state)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
       AddElement(this.dataGridFiles, new DataFile("A", "B", "C", "D"));
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.timer = new System.Threading.Timer(this.timerCallback, true, 1000, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
}

delegate void AddElementDelegateType(DataGrid dg, DataFile df);

AddElementDelegateType AddElementDelegate = (a, b) => ((ObservableCollection<DataFile>)(a.ItemsSource)).Add(b);

private void AddElement(DataGrid dg, DataFile df)
{
    if (!dg.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        Action<DataGrid, DataFile> act = new Action<DataGrid, DataFile>((a, b) => AddElement(a, b));
        dg.Dispatcher.Invoke(act, new object[] { dg, df });
    }
    else
        ((ObservableCollection<DataFile>)(dg.ItemsSource)).Add(df);
}
```